# Else if loop doesn't validate variable from statement

Tags: android, loops

I am having a problem while looping through one of my loop constructions.

I get Question instances out of my database and one of the fields of the instance is Attempts. I pulled my database from my device and inspected it and all fields of the column attempts are filled with ints greater than 0.

```
int initialAttempts = 0;
initialAttempts = c.getInt(6);
q.setAttempts(initialAttempts);
```

and in my custom array adapter:

```
if (mView != null) {

    int attempts =  getItem(position).getAttempts();
    int correctAnswer = getItem(position).getAnswerCorrect();
    triangle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    if(correctAnswer == 1) { 
        triangle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else if (correctAnswer != 1 && attempts > 0) { 
        triangle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        triangle.setImageResource(R.drawable.trianglered);
    }
```

So the problem is it never shows trianglered. If I drop the `&& attempts > 0`, it does show the trianglered, so I assume the error is in there. The strange thing is if I initialize attempts as 1 before the `getItem(position).getAttempts`, it still shows no trianglereds.

Any ideas where this goes wrong?

Comment: Can you show your `getAttempts()` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getItem(position).getAttempts()` method returns 0. There are no other variants. Why it returns 0 is the question to you. Prefer debugging instead of asking such questions.

PS. No need to check for `correctAnswer != 1` in `else if` statement. The opposite statement has already been checked  in `if` and it was false.